# C#, menustrip specific menu open when user have logged in

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

in my menuStrip i have multiple forms,

So in 1 of them i want to be access only when use is pass from a login form i have create..

Lets say menustrip, menu is on form1, and the login form is Form2,

So how i am gonna comebine this to so menustrip form open when the user first pass the form2 login..

i am searching all day over the net i found only by passing a variable and then if its true the form1 is gonna pop-out but it didnt work well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thinking I got it right "You want to have input in `form 1` from `form2`or something like modify something in form1 from form2"

It may not be the best but works

Well the simplest solution that has helped me till now is that you

1. Make `menuStrip` modifier from `properties` to  `public`
2. create an instance on `Form1` in `Form2`
3. Modify `menuStrip` from `Form2`

for example we can have

`Form2.cs`

```
 public partial class ViewCars : Form
    {
        Form1 mainForm;
        public ViewCars (Form1 MainForm)
        {
           this.mainForm = MainForm;
        }
    }

     private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         mainForm.menuStrip.Visible = false;
     }
```

Now to when you make the instance of `Form2` you need to have give parameter `this`
i.e

```
ViewCars view = new ViewCars(this);
view.Show();
```

This is not Limited to controls you can do anything with it
Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you will need to have a static Boolean property telling you if the user is logged in.

```
public static class Config {
    public static bool LoggedIn { get; private set; }

    public static Login ()
    {
        var frm = new frmLogin();
        if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            LoggedIn = frm.LoggedIn;
        }
    }
}
```

In `frmLogin` have again a public, but this time non-static property `LoggedIn`, which you set true if username and password are OK.

Then, in the menustrip form enable or disable the menu items accordingly in the form Activated event handler:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = Config.LoggedIn;
}
```

Comment: I exetended the example somewhat. It is more detailed on how to call the login form and how to return the result of the login process.